# convert bitmap to byte array

Tags: c++, windows, bitmap, arrays

How can I convert a bitmap to a byte array in c++ WITHOUT the .net framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you’re using Windows, you can use [`GetDIBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532334(VS.85).aspx) to retrieve the bitmap data.

Answer (score 0):

If your bitmap is a device independent bitmap, you can access the pixel data using GetObject and passing in a BITMAP. This avoids making a copy of the pixel data.